# Virtualize Linux Machine

Tags: linux, vmware, virtualization

I have one Linux BOX running Asterisk. I want to virtualize this machine, and put it in one VMWARE VM.

What is the best method and tools to do it?

Comment: You probably want to specify what OS Vmware will run under, what distro you run Asterix under, whether there is one physical box that will be converted or if Vmware will run on a different box, what architectures the box(-en) and OSs are, which CPUs are in the box(-en) and what kind of storage the Linux box runs from.

Answer (score 2):

[VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) can convert physical machines to VMs, among other things.